# Image resize increment file size

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I have a PHP script that uses [PhpThumb](http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/) to make a thumbnail of an uploaded picture. It's working with GD library; basically, under the save function, there is imagejpeg, imagegif and imagepng.

When I save a picture with quality 100, I have the file result with a size bigger than the original one!

For example, the original is an image 1024x768px with 163 Kb of size, and the resized image at 1024x682px has a size of 268 Kb!

Before I started using this library, I was doing all by myself, using the same imagejpeg, imagegif and imagepng function and making the thumb with imagecreatefromjpeg as similar function, but the result in size was the same!

So, do you know a way to resolve this problem? I think, it should not be possible that an image smaller than the original one is heavier than the original!

Thank in advise for the help!!

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The obvious 'solution' (if your problem is the increased file size) is to save with less than 100 quality.

Comment: yes, i know this solution. The strange thing is that the image saved at 100 of quality is bigger than the original... Why this?

Comment: It's because the original was saved with a quality of less than 100. You need to tune that parameter to find a setting that gives both acceptable image quality and size.

Comment: ok, txt! No other way with GD i suppose...